# How to add a href into a div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I would like to add `<a href='https://google.com'>` after a `<div>`.

Here is what I've been trying:

http://jsfiddle.net/L29e4ftj/

Is there someone who could help me out please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is that how do you want this ?

```html
<div id="autoComplete_list">

    <div data-id="2" class="autoComplete_result">
        <span class="autoComplete_highlighted">google</span>
    </div>
    
</div>

<script>
    
    var aUrl = document.createElement("a"); 
    aUrl.setAttribute("href", "https://google.com");
    aUrl.innerHTML = "<span class='autoComplete_highlighted'>Google</span>"
    

    document.querySelector("#autoComplete_list").appendChild(aUrl);

</script>
```

Comment: Updated i forgot something you wanted

Comment: This is the best so far, except it creates a new link, instead of just adding the href in front of the span. Should it be repaceChild instead of appendChild?

Comment: So Just remove `<span class="autoComplete_highlighted">google</span>` tag

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The way you are selecting the `div` is slightly wrong.

You use **getElementsByClassName()** which returns a **list** of elements, not a single element, so you will get `[div]` instead of `div`.

## Solution

You can either get the first element of that list:

`document.getElementsByClassName("autoComplete_result")[0]`

or use the simpler [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector()):

`document.querySelector(".autoComplete_result")` (which returns only **one** element, not an array).

```
window.onload=function() {

    // Notice the [0] which selects ONLY the first matched element
    var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("autoComplete_result")[0]; 
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href',"https://www.google.com");
    a.innerText = "google link";
    mydiv.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: What happened to getElementsByTagName ? If you don't need the class it is somehow more straightforward.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I don't understand what you are asking. Yes, there are other selectors you can use, but he only wants to select a specific element, not all elements of a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the getElementsByClassName is not returning as expected, so the appendChild is not working. I tried using querySelector and is working fine. Take a look at the code snippet below:

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelector('.autoComplete_result');
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href',"https://www.google.com");
a.innerText = "google link";
mydiv.appendChild(a);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="autoComplete_list">

      <div data-id="2" class="autoComplete_result">
          <span class="autoComplete_highlighted">goog</span>le
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```